# how to modify spring boot jpa generate table columns sequence

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my code,I create a class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_role")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class SysRole implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 主键
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    /**
     * 角色名,按照SpringSecurity的规范,以ROLE_开头
     */
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null comment '角色名,按照SpringSecurity的规范,以ROLE_开头'")
    private String name;

    /**
     * 角色名,中文
     */
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name_zh", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(255) not null comment '角色名,中文'")
    private String nameZh;

    /**
     * 排序
     */
    @Basic
    @OrderColumn(name = "sort")
    private Integer sort;

    /**
     * 是否启用
     */
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bit not null default 1 comment '是否启用'")
    private Boolean enabled;

    /**
     * 创建时间
     */
    @Basic
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "datetime not null default now() comment '创建时间'")
    private LocalDateTime createTime;

    /**
     * 创建用户
     */
    @CreatedBy
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "create_user")
    private SysUser createUser;

    /**
     * 修改时间
     */
    @Basic
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modify_time", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "datetime not null default now() comment '修改时间'")
    private LocalDateTime modifyTime;

    /**
     * 修改用户
     */
    @LastModifiedBy
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "modify_user")
    private SysUser modifyUser;

    /**
     * 备注
     */
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "remark")
    private String remark;

}
```

It will generate a table when I run
[image]

I find the columns sequence is

- id
- create_time
- enabled
- modify_time
- name
- name_zh
- remark
- ...

But I want to get this:

- id
- name
- name_zh
- create_time
- create_user
- modify_time
- modify_user
- ...

Why? I can not insert data faster when I use this sequence.

[image]

I need

[image]

In development environment,`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create`.So, I do not want to change the sequence every time by change database columns sequence.How to generate correct table columns sequence ?

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you need the columns in a predifined order?

Comment: Find important content faster and easier to understand the tables...or have a little obsessive....

Comment: If you want to control the order of columns then manually create the schema or use something like Flyway / Liquibase to generate the schema. Simply don't use hibernate schema creation as then you will leave it to hibernate to decide where the columns go.